# Silverlight sockets work fine except within IIS

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, iis

I am attempting to connect a silverlight client to a C# server process via sockets.  I have box A and box  B.  When I have both the server and client through Visual Studio on box A, it works fine.  When I deploy the server to IIS on box A, and go to the website hosting it on box A, it works fine.  When I connect to the server process on box A from a website hosted in visual studio on box B, everything works fine.

However, if I go to the website hosted on box A through IIS on box B, it's unable to connect to the server process on box A.  It never even connects to the policy server.  Since I can connect from box B using Visual Studio, I don't think it's a firewall issue.

Here's my policy file.  However, given that I can't even connect to the policy server from box B connecting to IIS, I doubt it's the problem.  http://pastebin.com/Z1vNNzg2

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what authentication are using using?  double hop ntlm issue?